# How to publish project on github-pages without committing the same files twice?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have several simple HTML/CSS/JS projects (one page, no backend) and I want to publish it on project Github Pages.

What is the best way to do it? Is it possible to do it without commiting the same files twice to `master` and `gh-pages` branches when I want to update something?

I could commit only to `gh-pages` but I think it is not the ideal solution because I have some files that are not related to the site content and which should be in master, such as readme. Also it is already committed to `master`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using your github.io page, the gh-pages branch is the right answer. I leave a README in master and gh-pages with the website only in the latter.